# Can I target all text HREF links which do not nclude an img?

Tags: css

I want to add a border to a link but only if the link contains text:

```
a, a:visited { border: 1px solid black; }
```

However this also adds a border to images that are linked:

```
<a><img src='...' /></a> <!-- I don't want a border around this -->
```

How would I just ensure any text or non-images inside the  tag get the border, but not the actual images?

Thanks very much!

Comment: you can't do that with just css. you can if you change your markup to give a class to text/image links. or you can use javascript.

Comment: Ok great, thank you!

Comment: np. if you can use jquery, it has `$.contains()` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

Comment: Very useful. Not using jquery this time but this helps, thanks :)

Comment: See also [Is there a CSS parent selector?](/q/1014861/5764553)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I appreciate it